# IPv6 autoconfiguration problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with stateful DHCPv6

Tags: networking

We try to implement IPv4 and IPv6 dual stack on customer network. Idea is to have out of the box experience for the end users. So we used auto DHCP setup.

With Windows 10 client I can get both addresses, IPv4 and IPv6 correctly set using stateful DHCPv6 and ICMPv6 in both scenarios - with WiFi router in between and once directly connected to border GW (bridged mode). traffic is passing on both IPv4 and IPv6.

In Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, however we observed different behavior. Ubuntu Desktop is using network manager for connection settings (out of the box) and IPv6 is enabled during the installation and in network manager GUI.

1. If I am connected behind WiFi router, Ubuntu is working out of the box but using SLAAC for IPv6 setup. Same is valid for Ubuntu server. we got default route on IPv6. IPv4 is working perfectly as well.
2. Once I am connected directly (or with bridge mode) to border GW, Ubuntu is getting IPv4 setup correctly but for IPv6 - only address and no IP6 default route and IP6 Gateway is set over ICMPv6. Border GW is using only Stateful DHCPv6 process, so no SLAAC. Same behavior is observe with out of the box Ubuntu server installation with netplan DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 set to auto (IPv6 enabled during install process and DHCP set to auto on both IPv4 and IPv6). As a result of this we got IPv6 address but no traffic on IPv6 (ping -6 [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is not passing through).
   Do you maybe some hints how to make Ubuntu work with both SLAAC and stateful DHCPv6?

Thank you in advnace.

Best regards,

Emil